# How to use two findElement in the same line?

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I have these code lines in my project. It supposed to click an element but when I run this code, my browser gets shut down. I don't know what causes that. Is it about the variables inside findElement?

```
List <WebElement> listItems=driver.findElement(RESULTCONT).findElements(MEDİA);
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", listItems);
```

Comment: Can you consider showing us your work & the relevant HTML DOM please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`arguments[0]` should be `webElement` and not `List`

Comment: How can I click the first element of listItems? I used this but doesn't work : driver.findElement(RESULTCONT).findElements(MEDİA).get(1).click();

Comment: ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", listItems.get(0));

Comment: or listItems.get(0).click();

Answer (score 0):

Here is the quick fix. From the list, get the first webelement and use the the same while passing the argument.

```
List <WebElement> listItems=driver.findElement(RESULTCONT).findElements(MEDİA);

// Getting the first webelement in the list and storing it
WebElement first = listItems.get(0);
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", first);
```